# How to make curve design in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a react native app and I need to create a curved screen design. How to create a curve design like the below screen.[image: Image scree design]

**This is what I tried here,**

[image: This is my sample screen]

**My sample codes,**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';      
export default class Home extends React.Component {     
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <View style={styles.container1}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container3}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container4}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  container1: {
    backgroundColor: '#3d06d6',
    height: hp('25%'),
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:100,
  },
  container2: {
    backgroundColor: '#0cad95',
    height: hp('25%'),
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:100,
  },
  container3: {
    backgroundColor: '#d6a606',
    height: hp('25%'),
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:100,
  },
  container4: {
    backgroundColor: '#06bad6',
    height: hp('25%'),
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:100,
  },
});
```

I want to curve my container edges like the first picture. I am able to make curves of the bottom edges. And How can I make curve designs like the first image? and also how can I add some animations into the container when I touch the container to open another screen? Is there any way to do this design using any style with "borderRadius" or any other way? And I don't want to use any library like react-native-svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your view inside a normal view and set the background colour of the next box which will give the output you need.

```js
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#0cad95' }}>
  <View style={styles.container1}>
    <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
  </View>
</View>
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#d6a606' }}>
  <View style={styles.container2}>
    <Text style={styles.name}>Container1</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: How can I add some animation to containers? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What type of animations ?

Comment: That means, How to add animation into containers like floating from top to bottom or slide from left to right?

Comment: You can check https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations, if you can come with some code then we can help :)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a **Linear Gradient** as the background. Just giving the color of the next box will not be the best option.

Assume "value" as the border-radius. ie the curve

Give a marginTop and paddingTop for each container.

```
marginTop : -value,
paddingTop : value,
```

Also assign zIndex in decending order for each container.

You can set zIndex with respect to the index, if you are looping through an array.

**Result**

[image]

**Sample code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

const data = ['', '', ''];
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View style={[styles.item, {zIndex: data.length - index}]}> // setting zIndex here
          <LinearGradient
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
          />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    height: 250,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,   // logic goes here
    marginTop: -100,               // move container
    paddingTop: 100,               // move inner item down
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
});

export default App;
```